# TFS configurations to support distributed teams

Tags: version-control, tfs

We are investigating using TFS for a small development group.  All the developers are remote to the office.  VPN is an option but not preferred, as we have to change vpn connections several times daily to support other functions in the business.

So I'm trying to figure out the different options that TFS can be configured with to support that model.  I've read about setting up Proxy Servers but that was using an older version of TFS so I'm not sure that still is/was the best option.

I haven't been able to locate good current documentation about the best/different ways to configure TFS to support this model.

I don't need comments about using Mercuial, GIT or something else.  I'm aware of them and including them in my overall evaluation but right now I'm trying to see what solutions TFS does or does not offer.  All developers have MSDN licenses and so TFS is free to the group.

Comment: When you say "TFS" do you mean "TFVC"?  The simplest solution for *TFS* is to use its distributed version control (Git).  But if you're evaluating TFS *with TFVC* then that's a different answer.

Comment: I had not seen the separate TFVC nomenclature as a component of TFS, but Yes I'm looking for recommendations, guidelines, and/or solutions to use TFS/TFVC with a distributed group.

Comment: Have you looked at the VSO option? Using a hosted central TFS instance would remove the need for VPN and improve collaboration...

Comment: In case it hasn't been made clear, Git is a source control option **in** TFS. You can create a team project backed by TFVC or by Git. You might already know that, but it hasn't been stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options (without VPN)

1) Like Martin suggested, look at VSO (Visual Studio Online, http://www.visualstudio.com) this is the cloud based version of TFS it's free for up to 5 developers.

2) Setup TFS internally inside your organization and make that instance available on the internet through your firewall.  You can secure it with certificates so only you team can connect in.  There is a lot of information on MSDN on how to secure it using SSL and certificate.

Cheers,
ET

Comment: The office wants it hosted internally so VSO is not really an option.  And I knew there was a web interface for TFS but only aware of the workflow aspect of it.  It has been over 4 years since I've had anything to do with TFS.  So you can configure Visual Studio to do checkin/checkout over the web?

Comment: Yes you can.  It's an endpoint.  So if you open your internal TFS to the web (and secure it with SSL and certificate) you can use VS and connect to it no problem.